# Create association by given nested attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have the following models (with associations):

```
Page has_and_belongs_to_many Dimension
```

I have a set of defined Dimensions in my app:

```
{id:1, width: 20, height:30}
{id:2, width: 40, height:60}
{id:3, width: 100, height:150}
```

When a user creates a page, I want to allow him setting an array of dimensions, such as:

```
Page.create({:page_name => 'test', :dimensions_attributes => [{:width => 20, :height => 30}, {:width => 40, height: 60}])
```

The problem with this approach is that it will create a new record of dimensions within my DB, and I don't want that. I want that the create method goes and tries to find the dimensions given the width and height provided.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add a method in your model for that, something like this:

```
def add_dimensions=(dimensions_attributes)
  dims.each { |attrs| dimensions << Dimension.find_or_create_by!(attrs) }
end
```

Then, you would need to replace `:dimensions_attributes` for `:add_dimensions` in your call to `Page.create`.

Comment: rabusmar, interesting, but at which point do I call that method? When I do ``Page.create({:page_name => 'test', :dimensions_attributes => [{:width => 20, :height => 30}, {:width => 40, height: 60}])`` it automatically creates the dimensions. How do I avoid that to happen?

Comment: @rabusmar I didn't know one could do that. Instead of calling "xxx_attributes", call a custom method to handle the nested attribute. Any links?

Comment: You can pass any custom method to the `attributes=` call (`new`, `build`, `create`, `update` all call it internally) and you can do whatever you want in that method. In fact, all `accept_nested_attributes_for` do is to create a writer. I don't have a link at hand but it's something I use all the time.